# Errors at named startup

Tags: centos, centos7, bind

I see this lines when i start `named`:

```
Sep 19 17:50:52 mydomain named[xxx]: ../../../../lib/isc/unix/socket.c:5682: unexpected error:
Sep 19 17:50:52 mydomain named[xxx]: setsockopt(22, TCP_FASTOPEN) failed with Protocol not available
```

What does it means? Should i worry? If so, how to fix it?

I don't know what is in `socket.c`. I run `locate scoket.c`, `find socket.c` and `find ~/ -type f -name "socket.c"`, and it did not find the file that is in the path `../../../../lib/isc/unix/socket.c`.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if TCP_FastOpen is enabled on your system.  CentOS ships with it either disabled or only available for outgoing connection.  You'll need to set it to 3 (enabled for both incoming and outgoing).  You can set this for the current session (for testing) with

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3
```

or

```
echo 3 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fastopen
```

If that resolves your issue and you want to set it permanently, then use

```
echo "net.ipv4.tcp_fastopen=3" > /etc/sysctl.d/30-tcp_fastopen.conf
```

Comment: I searched a bit and looks like i need to have a kernel version >= 3, my kernel version is `2.6.32-042stab139.1`, and these commands did not worked here, it said "No such file or directory". Is it ok to ignore this error that i showed in my question?

Comment: Then you have mis-tagged your post.  centos7 is based on RHEL7 which is 3.10 kernel.  You must be running centos6.  Where did you get the bind package you're using or did you build named by hand?  If you built it by hand, you need to rebuild it without the TCP_FASTOPEN option enabled.  If you got it from a package somewhere, you need to see if there's an updated package that doesn't have TFO enabled.

From what I can find, it will not work correctly if it can't set TFO.

Comment: No, i do use centos7, but in a container. I got `named` build from centos web panel. You said that i should rebuild `named` without the `TCP_FASTOPEN`, but is there any problem if i don't change anything? I mean, everything is working ok.